# Does c#/.net x.x have an implementation of a doubly linked list (that can be iterated over backwards)?

Tags: c#, .net, collections, linked-list, iteration

I've been searching for the standard implementation of a doubly linked list in c# (so that I have a linked list I can iterate over backwards) and cannot find one. I feel like something so simple must have an implementation that I'm just missing.

If it does exist, for which version of c#/.net does it exist?

Reverse iteration in general seems to be something not intended to be done in c#. Is my mind just stuck too much in c++/stl mode or is this something sorely lacking in c#?

I'm aware of LinkedList but in failing to find a way to iterate over it backwards had assumed it was singly linked.

If LinkedList is doubly linked how does one go about iterating over it backwards (Efficiently)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As well as the answers given here, you can write an extension method to `LinkedList<T>` to make it slightly easier to reuse:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Backwards<T>(this LinkedList<T> list)
{
    LinkedListNode<T> node= list.Last;
    while (node != null)
    {
        yield return node.Value;
        node = node.Previous;
    }
}
```

Use with:

```
foreach (string x in list.Backwards())
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm a little confused why something like this isn't just in the standard lib already.

Comment: @Catskul here's a good link that explains that http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx.

Comment: @Matt: Thanks. IMHO though, iterating backwards over a list is a more basic functionality than the "ForEach" discussed there (e.g. backwards iteration is provided by most STL containers) and in as much as it's not there, it almost seems like the C# creators were suggesting you shouldn't be doing it. In C#, even when I know how to do something by implementing it myself, I feel like if I didn't find a simple way, I must have missed something/be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 11):

The following code will efficiently iterate over a LinkedList in reverse:

```
        LinkedList<string> list = new LinkedList<string>
            (new[] {"cat", "dog", "frog", "antelope", "gazelle"});
        LinkedListNode<string> item = list.Last;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
            item = item.Previous;
        }
        while (item != null);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

The key here is that a LinkedList contains reference to only the First and Last LinkedListNode instances of the list. Each LinkedListNode instance holds a reference to the next and previous item in the list (or null at each end of the list) and also a Value property. This means iteration from the first or last LinkedListNode is easy, but random access requires iteration from the first or last in the list.

If you need to make an insertion along the way, use LinkedList.AddBefore or AddAfter to insert a new LinkedListNode.

Comment: Thats what I had been looking for. For some reason I was under the impression that List<T>.Last would return something of type T.

Thank you. Somehow you are the only person who seems to have understood the problem or even the concepts behind linked lists at all : /

Comment: A much underrated container. Glad to help.

Comment: This will throw an ArgumentNullException if the list is empty. Changing the do/while loop to a (simpler to read, IMO) while loop will solve the problem - see my answer for an example.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that and just converted to a while loop in my head without considering the implications of do/while.

Answer (score 2):

How about System.Collections.Generic.LinkedList()

Here are the docs on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx

**Version Info**
.NET Framework: Supported in: 3.5, 3.0, 2.0
.NET Compact Framework: Supported in: 3.5, 2.0
XNA Framework: Supported in: 3.0, 2.0, 1.0

That said, I am with the others that it is generally preferrable to use a higher abstraction when working with such a rich framework.

Comment: I have a specific need to be able to iterate over the list backwards, and to have cheap inserts + cheap reordering.

Comment: Okay, then the first part of my answer should help you.

Comment: RTFM is a not helpful especially since the docs do not specifically deal with reverse iteration. If we're just going to tell everyone to RTFM then why have Stackoverflow at all?

Comment: That is hardly a RTFM. You asked for the .net implementation of doubly linked lists and I gave you the name of the relevant framework object, answered your question about what versions of the framework support it and gave you a link to the documentation on it. You never asked for code to show reverse iteration, you just mused about whether it was intended to be done. The only question I didn't answer is the "Is my mind just stuck..." which I took as rhetorical.

Comment: Sorry I mis-interpreted you. The *"Okay, then the first part of my answer should help you"* response to my iteration commend seemed like an RTFM.

Answer (score 1):

How about [LinkedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx)?

Comment: How do you efficiently iterate over it backwards?

Comment: while (nodeP != null) nodeP = nodeP.Previous;